# Create a tree diagram (multiple parents) with pure HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, tree

I want to create a tree diagram with multiple parents. The idea is to create a diagram for Dota 2 Items, which several items can be made into one single item (plus a recipe), AND/OR one item can be made into several possibilities (more than one parent item).

[image]

One of my reference is from [thecodeplayer's code](http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/css3-family-tree).

Here is [my work](https://jsfiddle.net/sangprabo/o8dda3um) on jsfiddle so far.

```
<div class="items">
  <ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="">Dagon</a>
        <a href="#" class="">Veil of Discord</a>
        <a href="#" class="">Other Parent Item</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Null Talisman</a>
            <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Circlet</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mantle of Intelligence</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Recipe: Null Talisman</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
* {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-family: tahoma;
}

.items ul {
  padding-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

/* Make all children "inline" */
.items li {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;
}

/* Add horizontal connector. Note: they are 2 pseudo-elements */
.items li::before, .items li::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 45px;
  z-index: -1;
  border-top: 1px solid red;
}

.items li::after {
  border-left: 1px solid green;
  left: 50%;
  right: auto;
}

/* Remove left and right connector from a single child */
.items li:only-child::after, .items li:only-child::before {
  display: none;
}

.items li:only-child {
  padding-top: 0;
}

/* Remove "outer" connector */
.items li:first-child::before, .items li:last-child::after {
  border: 0 none;
}
/* Add back the down connector for last node */
.items li:last-child::before {
  border-right: 1px solid blue;
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}

/* Add curve line to the first child's connector */
.items li:first-child::after {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}


/* Add down connector from parent */
.items ul ul::before {
  content: '';
  border-left: 1px solid magenta;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 50%;
  width: 0;
}

/* Add cosmetic for each item */
.items li a {
  font-size: 12px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.items li a:hover {
  background-color: #EEE;
}

/* Experimental for multiple parents */
/* Add margin for the parents */
.items li a+a {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}
/* Implement also for the first parent */
.items li a:first-child {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

/* 
- Add "down" connector (vertical line) from each parent 
- Currently it will also select the single parent
*/
.items li > a:not(:only-child)::after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-right: 1px solid pink;
  top: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 0;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
}

/* Starting to fvcked up from here */

/* Making the horizontal connector line after each multiple parent */
.items li > a:not(:only-of-type):not(:last-of-type)::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: auto;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid indigo;
}

.items li > a:last-of-type:not(:first-child)::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  right: auto;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid indigo;
}
</style>
```

My attempts (which failed, or is not nice enough) is to create another pseudo-element (::before or ::after) the `<a>` (multiple parent) element.

Comment: why not just go for svg ?

Comment: @Arvind yes, that's an alternative solution. I am not sure the answer to this question, sir. I still believe that the problem is pretty simple and can be solved using purely with HTML and CSS. Thank you.

Comment: Here is my latest attempt : https://jsfiddle.net/sangprabo/o8dda3um/23/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I would recommend doing is setting the `left` property to `50%` on the left-most and right-most `::before` pseudo-classes, and then adjusting the `width` of the left-most and middle pseudo-classes to cover the offset.

I'd also recommend increasing the `top` of the downwards connectors by `2px` just to avoid spiky 'overhangs'.

A bit sloppy, but here's my attempt:

```css
* {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-family: tahoma;
}

.items ul {
  padding-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
}


/* Make all children "inline" */

.items li {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;
}


/* Add horizontal connector. Note: they are 2 pseudo-elements */

.items li::before,
.items li::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 45px;
  z-index: -1;
  border-top: 1px solid red;
}

.items li::after {
  border-left: 1px solid green;
  left: 50%;
  right: auto;
}


/* Remove left and right connector from a single child */

.items li:only-child::after,
.items li:only-child::before {
  display: none;
}

.items li:only-child {
  padding-top: 0;
}


/* Remove "outer" connector */

.items li:first-child::before,
.items li:last-child::after {
  border: 0 none;
}


/* Add back the down connector for last node */

.items li:last-child::before {
  border-right: 1px solid blue;
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}


/* Add curve line to the first child's connector */

.items li:first-child::after {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}


/* Add down connector from parent */

.items ul ul::before {
  content: '';
  border-left: 1px solid magenta;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px; /* Changed */
  left: 50%;
  width: 0;
}


/* Add cosmetic for each item */

.items li a {
  font-size: 12px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.items li a:hover {
  background-color: #EEE;
}


/* Experimental for multiple parents */


/* Add margin for the parents */

.items li a+a {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}


/* Implement also for the first parent */

.items li a:first-child {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}


/* 
- Add "down" connector (vertical line) from each parent 
- Currently it will also select the single parent
*/

.items li>a:not(:only-child)::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-right: 1px solid pink;
  top: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 0;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
}


/* Starting to fvcked up from here */


/* Making the horizontal connector line after each multiple parent */

.items li>a:not(:only-of-type):not(:last-of-type)::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: auto;
  width: 110%; /* Changed */
  border-top: 1px solid indigo;
}

.items li>a:last-of-type:not(:first-child)::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  right: auto;
  width: 42%; /* Changed */
  border-top: 1px solid indigo;
}


/* ADDED STYLES */
.items li>a:first-of-type:first-child::before {
  left: 50%;
}

.items li>a:last-of-type:last-child::before {
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="">Dagon</a>
      <a href="#" class="">Veil of Discord</a>
      <a href="#" class="">Other Parent Item</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Null Talisman</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Circlet</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mantle of Intelligence</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Recipe: Null Talisman</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: May I ask how do you calculate the `42%` and `110%` width? I modified your code a bit, and here is my final code so far. https://jsfiddle.net/sangprabo/o8dda3um/23/. I am still working on some cases, where the multiple parents is on the second (middle) level of tree (for example, at the same level with the "Null Talisman" element). But, that's a very rare case.

You just gave me an idea to use the correct selector. Thank you very much, Sir.